# iOS Accessibility on TableViewCell with inner CollectionView

Tags: ios, uitableview, accessibility, uicollectionviewcell, voiceover

I'm working on supporting Accessibility for our iOS app (in Swift). I have `UITableViewCell`s with an inner `CollectionView`(with inner ImageView per cell), which looks like this:

[image]

By default, when I tap on the parent view (TableViewCell), it reads the 2 labels, and when I tap on the CollectionView cells, it reads the name of the image in the cell. However, some labels and images have different accessibility values, so I had to set them manually.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let tableViewCell = cell as? MyParentTableView {
            tableViewCell.isAccessibilityElement = true
            tableViewCell.accessibilityLabel = getCorrectAccessibilityLabel()
        }
    }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // sample only
    if let myCell = cell as? MyCollectionViewCell {
        myCell.isAccessibilityElement = true
        myCell.accessibilityValue = getCorrectAccessibilityLabel()
    }
}
```

When I did that, the parent view blocks the whole view, so I can no longer focus the accessibility box on the CollectionView cells and VoiceOver does not read them out anymore. I tried setting the TableView's accessibility first, then the accessibility of each CollectionView cell, and also using `accessibilityElements` in the TableView, but it does not seem to be working.

```
// TableViewCell's awakeFromNib function    
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    self.collectionView.dataSource = self
    self.collectionView.delegate = self

    self.accessibilityElements = [self, self.collectionView]
}
```

EDIT: Posted some code.

Appreciate any help or insight. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the problem is that you can't click on the collection because always the app thinks that you click on the row, right?
Have you tried to disable the selection of the row and put a invisible view under the collection with the same width and height of the row and with a touchRecognition? If you click on the view is like you clicked on the row, but I think this can solve your problem.

One other tip: Don't put the settings of the delegate in the awakeFromNib method, because sometimes this method is not called. It depends on the objects created. Put it always in the viewDidLoad().